# How does luggage work with Multi-leg travel on a single ticket?

Tags: transit, luggage, international-travel, klm

I have booked a flight from Lahore Pakistan to Toronto via Dammam and Amsterdam. Lahore to Dammam is operated by PIA, while the rest is with KLM. A ticket for the complete journey has been issued by KLM, while both airlines have given separate booking numbers.

Now the questions.

1. Which airline is responsible for any claims throughout?
2. Shall my baggage be handled from Lahore up to Toronto directly?
3. PIA has changed the departure of my first flight 6 hours earlier than originally scheduled. Can I ask KLM to provide facilities as the total layover time at Dammam becomes 11 hours?

Comment: The edit to the title results in it no longer matching the question…

Answer (score 9):

> Which Airline is responsible for any claims throughout?

That depends on what happens when and where. Typically the "operating carrier" handles any irregularities with a specific flight. If something comes up in Lahore, you will need to talk to PIA simply because KLM has no presence in Lahore.

> Shall my baggage be handled from Lahore up to Toronto directly?

Yes.

> PIA has scheduled the departure 6 hours earlier than scheduled. Can I ask KLM to provide facilities as the total Layover time at Dammam becomes 11 hours?

No. When a schedule change like this happens your options are typically:

1. Accept the change as is
2. Ask for rerouting or rebooking (if there is a reasonable alternative), or
3. Cancel the flight for a full refund.

**Caveat**: There are exceptions to every rule so none of this is guaranteed and if you want to be 100% sure, talk to the airlines directly. Some of this also depends on the details: class of service fare class and fare rules, how the ticket was booked, interlining agreements, etc.

Comment: Good answer, but I think the singular "Yes." might be a bit strong for something to which the final caveat definitely applies often enough. Having encountered multiple exceptions to that 'rule' I would recommend to always check at check-in whether the luggage is checked all the way through. Based on exceptions we encountered I think it's especially when either one of the airlines is a budget airline or when one of the legs is a domestic leg. Point is, "Yes." should probably be replaced with "Most likely.". We always ask at luggage drop off/check in.

Comment: Note: you have a single ticket, so the airline must provide enough time (or rebook) if you have to do baggage claim and check it again. Not really what you asked, but it may reassure you. And at first checking you will discover the airport you should claim the baggage.